# Deserialize object error error when reading a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I have the next response from an API

```
{
  "ArticleSpecification": [
    {
      "Name": "SomeName",
      "Description ": "Description ",
      "Label": "SomeLabel",
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I try to Deserialize the object using my class

```
public class ArticleSpecification
    {
        [JsonProperty("Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Label")]
        public string Label { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

The deserialize section looks like this

```
    if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var json = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

List<ArticleSpecification>  articles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ArticleSpecification>(json);
            }
```

The result is the next :

```
Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Program+ArticleSpecification]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object
```

Answer (score 3):

The response from API is an object, not the array.

Your response actually is an object, which has the property: ArticleSpecification which is the array. Example of class for such reponse:

```
class APIResponse {
    public ArticleSpecification[] ArticleSpecification { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize response:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResponse>(json);
List<ArticleSpecification> articles = new List<ArticleSpecification>(response.ArticleSpecification);
```

Something among those lines.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think you would have to use an array in `APIResponse` and then create a list from it. You should just be able to make it a `List<ArticleSpecification>`.

Comment: @MattU Your right about that, it just slipped my mind